# Solve $a^2+b^n=c^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $a,b,c$ be co-prime integers >1, for all $n>2$, I need help finding the integral solutions of the  diophantine equation $a^2+b^n=c^2$. I saw the result but I am curious about to how to get there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could be solved as follows. Note that we have
$$
  c^2 - b\bigl(b^{(n-1)/2}\bigr)^2 = a^2.
$$
Now $$(c,b^{(n-1)/2},a)=\biggl(\frac{r^2+bs^2}{t},\frac{2rs}{t},\frac{r^2-bs^2}{t}\biggr)$$ for some integers $r,s,t$ with $t \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Very simply:  $$a^2+b^{n}=c^2$$

Degradable trên multipliers.  $$c^2-a^2=(c-a)(c+a)=b^{n}=qt$$

Solutions obtained:  $$a=\frac{t-q}{2}$$  $$c=\frac{t+q}{2}$$

It's easier. Can a formula in another form to write, but the expression is long and still nobody wants.
You can write such a formula.

$$a=k^{n}(2(p-s))^{n-2}-(p-s)^2$$

$$b=2k(p-s)$$

$$c=k^{n}(2(p-s))^{n-2}+(p-s)^2$$

Comment: ,thanks for your input. However,the flaw that I've found so far in your reasoning is if for instance $b$ only has $2$ as primes, then $t$ and $q$ are both pair integers. As a result,$a,b,c$ must be pair, thereby non-relatively prime.

Comment: @Andy Why? Must be the same parity. They can be not even.

Comment: you mean $a,b$ must be the same parity. I apologize. I was wrong. just out of curiosity, what's the other expression or formula are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks. I found a similar set of solutions but for all $n>2, $ isn't $p-s$ is a common factor to $a,b,c$?